# Make win+m followed by win+p execute code

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey, hotkeys

What shoud I do to execute some code (ie: `MsgBox "Hello"`) by:

1. Pressing <kbd>win</kbd>+<kbd>m</kbd>
2. Unpressing <kbd>m</kbd> whithout unpressing <kbd>win</kbd>
3. Pressing <kbd>p</kbd>

Comment: I don't see your point. You can hold `win+m` as long as you wish before pressing `p` and releasing all three keys afterwards.

Comment: Thank you. You help me understand that in fact "quite fast" means as long as `win+m` is still pressed. This is the problem. I edited my question and will try to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like there's a good answer already, I just wanted to input what I could think of, so here's a version of the earlier answer, but without `Send`s.
I'd say a solution without them is always desirable, though, of course, in something as small as this, you'll struggle to find any difference in practice.

```
;runs after m is released on a LWin+m press
<#m up::
    Hotkey, <#p, WinMP_Callback, On     ;Enable LWin+p hotkey
    KeyWait, LWin                       ;wait for LWin to be released
    if (A_PriorKey = "m")
        WinMinimizeAll                  ;keep win+m functional
    Hotkey, <#p, , Off                  ;disable LWin+p hotkey
return

WinMP_Callback()
{
    ;do stuff

    ;add this at the end if you dont want
    ;to be able to keep running this function
    ;on subsequent presses of p before LWin is released
    ;Hotkey, <#p, , Off
}
```

So pretty much what the difference here is toggling the `LWin+p` hotkey on and off and just using [`WinMinimizeAll`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinMinimizeAll.htm) instead of sending `LWin+m`, since they're the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<#m::                  ; "<#" means "LWin"
    LWin_m := true     ; assign the Boolean value "true" or "1" to this variable
    KeyWait, LWin, L   ; wait for LWin to be released
    LWin_m := false
return

<#p::
    If (LWin_m)        ; If this variable has the value "true" 
        msgbox "Hello"
    ; else
        ; do sth else
return
```

**EDIT:**

For not losing normal `win+m` and `win+p` try this:

```
<#m::                      ; "<#" means "LWin"
    LWin_m := true         ; assign the Boolean value "true" or "1" to this variable
    KeyWait, LWin, L       ; wait for LWin to be released
    If (A_PriorKey = "m")
        Send #m     
    LWin_m := false
return

<#p::
    If (LWin_m)  ; If this variable has the value "true" 
        msgbox "Hello"
    else
        Send #p
return
```